# Minimum Adjustment Cost

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this question:

> Given an integer array, adjust each integers so that the difference of
>    every adjacent integers are not greater than a given number target.
>
> If the array before adjustment is A, the array after adjustment is B,
>    you should minimize the sum of `| A[i]-B[i] |. You can assume each number in the array is a positive integer and not greater than 100.

`

I see a dp solution but I don't quite understand the recurrence equation.

```
public static int MinAdjustmentCost(ArrayList<Integer> A, int target) {
    // write your code here
    if (A == null || A.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // D[i][v]: 把index = i的值修改为v，所需要的最小花费
    int[][] D = new int[A.size()][101];

    int size = A.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
            D[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if (i == 0) {
                // The first element.
                D[i][j] = Math.abs(j - A.get(i));
            } else {
                for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
                    // 不符合条件 
                    if (Math.abs(j - k) > target) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int dif = Math.abs(j - A.get(i)) + D[i - 1][k];
                    D[i][j] = Math.min(D[i][j], dif);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        ret = Math.min(ret, D[size - 1][i]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Adjusting is changing the element to any positive integer less than or equal to 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to minimize the cost of the adjustment, which is the value you increase/decrease every element such that the difference between every adjacent elements is less than or equal to `target`. The dp solution is to try every possible value and minimize the cost on the valid ones (when `abs(A[i]-A[i-1]) <= target`)

First thing is to fill the cost for adjusting first element to 1-100 which is done here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
            D[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // fill with MAX_VALUE because we want to minimize
            if (i == 0) {
                // for the first element we just set the cost of adjusting A[i] to j
                D[i][j] = Math.abs(j - A.get(i));
            }
```

Now you have `D[0][j]` as the cost to adjust the first element to be `j`. Then for every other element, you loop again (from `k = 1` to `k = 100`) for other elements and try to change `A[i]` to `j`. And then you check if `abs(k-j)` is valid (less than or equal to `target`) then you can adjust `A[i]` to be `j` and `A[i-1]` to be `k` so you minimize on `D[i][j]`.

Here `D[i][j]` means the cost of changing `A[i]` to `j` and `D[i-1][k]` is the cost of changing `A[i-1]` to `k`. so for every `k` and `j` if they are valid (`abs(k-j)<=target`) then you add them together and minimize the value saved in `D[i][j]` so you can use it for next element, which is done here:

```
else {
    for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
        // if abs(j-k) > target then changing A[i] to j isn't valid (when A[i-1] is k)
        if (Math.abs(j - k) > target) {
            continue;
        }
        // otherwise, calculate the the cost of changing A[i] to j and add to it the cost of changing A[i-1] to k
        int dif = Math.abs(j - A.get(i)) + D[i - 1][k];
        // minimize D[i][j]
        D[i][j] = Math.min(D[i][j], dif);
     }
}
```

At the end, you need to loop from 1 to 100 at the last element and check which is the minimum value over all, which is done here:

```
int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    ret = Math.min(ret, D[size - 1][i]);
}
```

I think if you split the initialization code and the DP calculation code it would be easier to understand, for example:

```
// fill the initial values
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; ++j) {
        // on the first element just save the cost of changing
        // A[i] to j
        if (i == 0) {
            DP[i][j] = abs(j-A.get(i));
        } else {
            // otherwise intialize with MAX_VALUE
            D[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;        
        }

    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
        for (int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
            // if abs(j-k) isn't valid skip it
            if (Math.abs(j - k) > target) {
                continue;
            }
            // if it is valid, calculate the cost of changing A[i] to j
            // and add it to the cost of changing A[i-1] to k then minimize
            // over all values of j and k
            int dif = Math.abs(j - A.get(i)) + D[i - 1][k];
            D[i][j] = Math.min(D[i][j], dif);
        }
    }
}

// calculate the minimum cost at the end
int ret = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    ret = Math.min(ret, D[size - 1][i]);
}
```